# Googlesheets: get data from a cell which contains a few string

Tags: google-sheets

Initially I use `=transpose(IMPORTXML("https://www.coingecko.com/en/watchlists/all-time-high-crypto","/html/body/div[4]/div[6]",3))` to get a list of coins data.

However, it is not in a table form and it is `[image]

How can I use VLOOKUP (or any method) to find `ETH` and get the data for `ATH` which is `$4,878.26`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=index(xlookup(B1&"*",trim(A:A),--regexextract(A:A,"ATH:\s+\$(.*?) "),,2))
```

[image]

Comment: It works! Could elaborate trim and index combine to work for this case?

Comment: the raw data that's being pulled via importxml has leading spaces to the text; so trim() is to clear that off and index is just used as an arrayformula here.